# Global mock with mocha

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-mocha

I have many tests for my class.
When I added check for file existence, in my class.

I needed to add this code in all my cases.

```
File.any_instance.
    expects(:exist?).
    with('test_file').
    returns(true).
    once()
```

But I want declare a global mock for all my tests, can I make this with mocha and rspec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would do this like follows:

```
describe Thing do

  # If this is really done once...

  before :all do
    File.any_instance.expects(:exist?).with('test_file').returns(true).once
  end

  # If this is done once per example...

  before :each do
    File.any_instance.expects(:exist?).with('test_file').returns(true).once
  end

  # ...

end
```